# Python Tkinter -- object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a gui using tkinter, i need to work with a login window and subsequent windows, i am unable to place any label on new windows as it says 'testclass' object has no attribute 'tk'

My main objective is to create a new window after logging in and hiding the login window and then work with the new window and place label and create a form

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm


class LoginFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()


    # def verifycred(self,username,password):


    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # verify_out = self.verifycred(username,password)

        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = randomclass(self.newWindow)

class randomclass(LoginFrame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Random Class")
        self.master.geometry("1350x750+250+150")
        self.master.config(bg ='cadet blue')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'powder blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        self.test = Button(self.frame,text='Random',width = 25, command = self.random)
        self.test.grid(row=4,column=0)



    def random(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = testclass(self.newWindow)
class testclass(LoginFrame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Test")
        self.master.geometry("1350x750+250+150")
        self.master.config(bg ='cadet blue')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'powder blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        self.welcome = Label(self,text='Hello')
        self.welcome.grid(row=0,column=1)



root = Tk()
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forgot to add self.master in the label widget of testclass .Its just a small problem.You have to apply grid layout to testclass frame also. Because the remaining label is defined in grid layout.

Comment: I am sorry if i seem like a noob, but i am that. can you please show me where to edit the code? Thankyou soo much

Comment: I edited it, now the error appears as _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!toplevel.!toplevel which already has slaves managed by pack

Comment: change frame widget layout to grid.

Answer (score 0):

There's Only small problem that you are forgot to write self.master inside a label widget declaration of testclass.

Here's The Solution,

```
class testclass(LoginFrame):

def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.master.title("Test")
    self.master.geometry("1350x750+250+150")
    self.master.config(bg ='cadet blue')
    self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'powder blue')
    self.frame.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

    self.welcome = Label(self.master,text='Hello')
    self.welcome.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Comment: how to hide the login frame after successful login without killing the program

Comment: Thanks a lot tho, it worked now only thing left is hiding the login screen

Comment: For that you just have to define a function that append login data to a specific list and then destroy that Login window.

Comment: you are missing super().__init__() from your derived class